# Where does forefront log which files have been scanned?

Tags: anti-virus, logging

Does forefront keep a log of files that have been scanned?

And if so where does this log exist?

Answer (score 0):

See the following link for a list of log files that Forefront creates, that should be what you are looking for.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418913.aspx